# analysis of 도 in 아/어도 되다

Tags: grammar, word-origin

I am studying about 아/어도 되다 pattern from [this site](http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%EC%95%84/%EC%96%B4_%2B_%EB%8F%84_%EB%90%98%EB%8B%A4). I understand this structure and how it is used in a sentence. However, I am really curious about the word 도. Does anyone have a deep analysis why the word is used here or maybe its origin to make it have that meaning?

Answer (score 2):

> 되다 : We are in a suitable or permitted state
>
> 도 : 보조사 auxiliary. Except the previous, it tells that there is another similar thing.

Someone A breaks the traffic rule so that policeman
ask identification card. After some investigation, A talks

가도 돼요 ? Is it possible that I will go = Do you finish a report ?

Comment: Where do you get that definition for 도? I don't think it means that in this case.